# How can i sorting combobox items on React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a project and in project there is a year combobox. I will the year sorting(asc to desc or desc to asc).

[image]

I have a form utils and I call the utils in a component.

Comment: Nobody can help you until you provide enough information on your problem. At least you can include the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

function compare(a, b) {
  return a.label > b.label ? 1 : b.label > a.label ? -1 : 0;
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          label: 1940,
          value: 1
        },
        {
          label: 1945,
          value: 2
        },
        {
          label: 1942,
          value: 3
        },
        {
          label: 1941,
          value: 4
        },
        {
          label: 1946,
          value: 5
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        //isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        options={this.state.options.sort(compare)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an [Example on Snack.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj28n553o5?file=/src/index.js:0-833)